# Rearranging columns of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with tds having id, I need to rearrange the column order.

```
$('table tr').each(function() {
    var tds = $('#Status');
    var tdA = $('#Address');
    alert(tds.innerHtml);           //Here am getting a blank msg              
    tds.remove().insertAfter(tda);  //This is what i need to do 
});
```

Comment: please share your html as well.. looks like you have `#Status` and `#Address` in every row.... ID of an element must be unique

Comment: you selecting allways the same ID's, `$('#Status')` so they might be duplicate

Comment: actually this is a asp repeater

Comment: dynamically generated so i am having it in every row

Comment: my html is a hell lot of code , How can i replace it , what should i do if i make it a class ??

Comment: Why don't you fix the server-side code instead of using JavaScript? Seems to be [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example with **classes** used: http://jsfiddle.net/eT5pL/
Working example with **ids** used: http://jsfiddle.net/eT5pL/1/

As an additional note you shouldn't have duplicate Ids.
Double check that `'#Status'` shouldn't be `'.Status'`

```
$('table tr').each(function() {
    var tds = $(this).find('#Status'); //find the child of the row
    var tdA = $(this).find('#Address'); //find the child of the row           
    tds.remove();
    $(tds).insertAfter(tdA);
});
```

Comment: this cant be right!! Same ID's... `$(this).find('.Status')`

Comment: _"it is allowed in HTML5"_? Are you referring to duplicate IDs? No, that's not true. IDs _must_ be unique.

Comment: It is true in this case..., but still you should avoid it!

Comment: @reyaner I don't disagree, I would never do it :)

Comment: @undefined **The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree** From: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute